# Issue with TextInput on Expo React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

So I'm doing a login page, for that I'm using the TextInput, reading the documentation I found the inlineImageLeft props, that allows me to put an icon on the input. The documentation tells me to position the icon on the `/android/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder... although expo doesn't have the Android Folder, in the [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/textinput/#inlineimageleft) it's said the same thing.

Is there any way to use this without having the android folder?

Comment: Its for bare Workflow